# Twitter Streaming API: Is it possible to filter only tweets that have co-ordinates?

Tags: python, api, twitter, streaming

I've got the following code that filters for a specific location span, but I really want it to only return tweets that have location co-ordinates. At the moment it will return 'None' if there aren't any, but I want to ignore them completely. Any ideas?

```
  loc = [-3.72,50.29,-3.42,50.41]

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):

        try:
            print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (status.text,
                                      status.author.screen_name,
                                      status.created_at,
                                      status.source,
                                      status.coordinates)          

        except Exception, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e
            pass

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout=60)

streaming_api.filter(follow=None, locations=loc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to drop elements that are None from a list, you can do it like this :

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', None, 'c', None]
>>> filter(None, l)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm looking to filter them from the stream before they even get into the list. Twitter limits the number of tweets you can stream so I want to filter it at source.